# How do I remove the one "like" from that particular user?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-livewire

Trying do create a "like system" for a simple application with Laravel and Livewire. I have managed to add likes, but I only want the user to be able to add one (1) like to a post. At the moment a user can add as many likes as he or she wants.

This is my current function to store likes:

```php
    public function storeLike()
    {
        // Check if the user already has liked the post
        if($this->collection->likes()->exists()){
            return $this->collection->likes()->delete();
        }

        // If not, add one like to the db
        $like = $this->collection->likes()->make();
        $like->user()->associate(auth()->user());

        // Save the like
        $like->save();
    }
```

And the part that im struggling with is:

```php
        if($this->collection->likes()->exists()){
            return $this->collection->likes()->delete();
        }
```

It deletes all the likes for that post. So how can a disassociate, detach that like if it exists?

This is how I have made the collection:

```php
        $collection = collect();

        $posts = Post::search('topic', $this->search)->with(['user'])->latest()->get();
        $urls = Urls::search('topic', $this->search)->with(['user'])->latest()->get();
        $news = News::search('topic', $this->search)->latest()->get();

        /** Push posts to the collection */
        foreach ($posts as $post) $collection->push($post);
        /** Push urls to the collection */
        foreach ($urls as $item) $collection->push($item);
        /** Push news to the collection */
        foreach ($news as $item) $collection->push($item);
```

Comment: Is your collection an Eloquent model or a collection?

Comment: What is `$this->collection` ?

Comment: Sorry for that. I have edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

I think the `toggle` (see [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#toggling-associations)) method could be very handy.

Let's assume we're building a component for a model called `Post`.

**Livewire**

```
public function clickedLike() {
    $this->post->likes()->toggle(Auth::user());
}
```

**Template**

```
<button wire:click="clickedLike">
    <3
</button>
```

**Model**

```
class Post extends Model {
    public function likes() {
        return $this->hasMany(User::class, 'likes')
    }
}
```